# Returning PHP value to the page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a remote php program that generates 2 random numbers, I call to it on my form page to populate a text box used in validation. I can't get it to return the numbers.

```
<?php
    $randomNum = rand(0,9);
    $randomNum2 = rand(0,9);
    echo ($randomNum + $randomNum2);
    $randomNumTotal = $randomNum + $randomNum2;
?>
```

It is returning the total, not # + #
Please help!

OK, thanks to the help below I got the output to be correct on the page. What I'm doing is the parent page brings in forms via AJAX. The forms are validated by a remote PHP script "random.php" in the forms there is a math problem for a somewhat human verification, the math problem is populated by the "random.php" file via .get command. Got that working. The issue now is that I can't solve the problem correctly... the answer input has this validation:

```
SomeName: {
    equal: "<? php echo $randomNumTotal ?>
}
```

but it's  not working...any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you want echo to return "5 + 5" instead of "10"?

Comment: @tylermwashburn - yes, I have the output working, now its a validation issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the `.` in php for String concatenation

Try `$randomNumTotal = $randomNum ."+". $randomNum2;`

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to concatenate the digits rather than add them, which is `.` rather than `+`:

```
echo $randomNum . $randomNum2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
echo $randomNum, ' + ', $randomNum2;
```

Comment: I actually was able to figure that one out. Now it doesn't want to validate when you do add them...

Answer (score 1):

`+` is an addition, while `.` is a string concatenation:

```
echo $randomNum . '+' . $randomNum2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
echo "$randomNum + $randomNum2 = " . $randomNum + $randomNum2;

Comment: for the output or the validation?